# How to convert list of 68 elements into matrix of 68x68?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a list `[1,2,3,4,5...,68]` I want it to make as `[[1,1,1....68 times],[2,2,2...68 times],.....[68,68,68... 68 times]]`.
i.e. If I consider list as a matrix then I have 68x1 matrix want to make it 68x68 by repeating elements in column, just like a repmat [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) in MATLAB.

I tried np.tile like this

```
np.tile(y_1,(1,68))
```

where y_1 has 68 elements but it ended up giving as [1,2,3,4....68]

I also tried

```
y_1*68
```

but it gave `[1,2,3,4....68,1,2,3,4.....68,1,2...68....]` which is again not I want

How can I do this ?

Comment: You have added the `numpy` tag, but the data structure you show is not a `numpy` data structure, but rather a list of lists. Can you clarify that you in fact want a list of lists, or actually a matrix/multidimentional array?

Comment: I added numpy because I used numpy tile functions as a solution and as I was searching for this question I found np.tile() shoould work perfectly, but it didn't so I wanted to clarify the issue. I actually want it in the form of multidimensional list.

Comment: There is no such thing as a multidimentional list.  You can have a list of lists, or a multidimentional `numpy` array.  You will have to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `list comprehension`.

```
lis = [1,2,3,4,5]
rep = [[i]*len(lis) for i in lis]
print(rep)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

Comment: How bout if we want to use it in opposite way i.e. output should be [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]] i.e. it should repeat rows wise ?

Comment: @Eyshika Thats even easier. `[lis for i in range(3)]` or `[lis]*3`(not `lis*3` Try both and see the difference :) ), where `lis = [1,2,3,4,5]`. Btw I think you should really read about `list comprehension`. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

#### with a list comprehension.

```
mat = range(1, 69)
[[elt]*len(mat) for elt in mat]
```

#### You can replicate the matlab repmat function like this:

```
def repmat(mat):
    return [[elt]*len(mat) for elt in mat]

repmat([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

#### output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 1, 1, 1], 
 [2, 2, 2, 2], 
 [3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

#### Alternatively, with a lambda:

```
repmat2 = lambda mat:[[elt]*len(mat) for elt in mat]
repmat2([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 np.tile(np.reshape(y_1,(68,1)),(1,68))
```